# Load Error rack/test

Tags: ruby

I am getting following error when running a test file.

```
$ruby test/test_gothonweb.rb
/Users/sony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/test (LoadError)
    from /Users/sony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from test/test_gothonweb.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Snippet of the test file:

```
require_relative '../lib/gothonweb.rb'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rack/test'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

class GothonwebTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
    include Rack::Test::Methods

    def app
        Sinatra::Application
    end
end
```

I think the gem is installed and should be available:

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (0.9.0)
rvm (1.11.3.3)
sinatra (1.3.2)
tilt (1.3.3)
```

Why the error you think?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`rack-test` is a separate gem. Include that in your Gem file.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue here, and by `gem uninstall rack-test` and then bundle install solved the issue.

https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/issues/123